# Terraria iOS: how to get my old world back?

Tags: ios, terraria-mobile

I rather recently got a new phone, and it has all of the same information as my old iPhone. However, I had to completely start over on terraria because I can't get my world on my new phone. Keep in mind that on my old phone (which doesn't work), I didn't have the world on cloud save. I have Game Center set up and everything. Is there a way to recover this world?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**There are no ways to recover your world**, unless it was on cloud save, or the old device is working.

***If it was on cloud save:***

Just download back your save.

***If the old device is working:***

Switch the save to a cloud save, or move the files of your save through a file management tool like [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) or [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) etc.

*If you are on Android, the data directory is* `data/data/com.and.games505.Terraria/files` or `data/data/com.and.games505.TerrariaPaid/files`

You'll need a root capable file explorer (and have your phone rooted) on both your devices in order to be able to access it.

***If you have a backup of the old device:***

Install that backup to a device (don't forget to backup that device first!), move the save files out of the device using a file management tool like [iFunbox](http://www.i-funbox.com/) or [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) etc., then install the backup of the device you took before installing the backup, and move the save files back in.